# Конвертация из Char в Hex

Tags: c, строки, char, hex, системы-счисления

Как сделать конвертацию обратно из Hex в Char.
Мне нужно положить Hex значение слова "test" в массив(наверное char), и я не понимаю как это сделать

```
int main (){

    char* str = "test";

    printf("0x%p\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

все я решил, нельзя из Hex переводить сразу в чар!

Comment: я не понимаю как положить с принтф в переменную

Comment: printf - функция, которая выводит строку, она ничего не возвращает, и с нее вы ничего не "положите". Уточните вопрос, добавьте описание того, как по-вашему должна работать ваша программа

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я так понимаю что я должен положить Hex значение слова "test" в переменную, и я не понимаю как это сделать, только это смог найти, после этого я попробую перевести из Hex обратно в char

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define I2A(v) "0123456789ABCDEF"[v]
#define DUMP_CHAR(c) printf("0x%c%c ", I2A((c>>4) & 0xF), I2A(c & 0XF))
#define DUMP_STR(str, str_len)                      \
  do {                                              \
    int i;                                          \
    for(i=0; i < str_len; ++i)                      \
    {                                               \
      DUMP_CHAR(str[i]);                            \
    }                                               \
  } while(0)

int main()
{
  const char str[]="012345";
  int str_len = sizeof(str)/sizeof(*str);

  DUMP_STR(str, str_len);

  return 0;
}
```

пример вывода:
$./to_hex
0x30 0x31 0x32 0x33 0x34 0x00
где:
0x30 -> '0'
0x31 -> '1'
0x32 -> '2'
0x33 -> '3'
0x34 -> '4'
0x00 -> нуль терминация строки.

если мы будем определять длину строки используя функцию strlen(), то длина строки вернется *без* терминирующего нуля и вывод *не* будет содержать "0x00"

Comment: Неполохо бы  еще словами в ответе объяснить про последний нолик, который читатель (?) увидит  в печати (откуда он берется, как связан с sizeof, и что будет для strlen)

Answer (score 7):

У вас настолько непонятно, что вы хотите, что ответить вам всерьез не получается.

Держите вариант :)

```
unsigned long s = 'test';
printf("%lX\n",s);
```

Вывод `74657374` и есть представление `test` в шестнадцатеричном виде.

Только преподу не показывайте... :)

Comment: Спасибо,как положить этот ответ в переменную?

Comment: Еще раз - это хак, основанный на том, что test - из 4 символов. Коды и так лежат в переменной `s`. Поймите, в компьютере **нет** десятичных, шестнадцатеричных или двоичных форматов - это все представления при вводе-выводе, не более того. Так что лежит ли в переменной 47, 00101111 или 2F - это все одно и то же...

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я понял, вот только не понимаю как взять это значение , чтобы перести его обратно

Comment: Очередной финт:     `char * c = (char*)&s;
    printf("%c%c%c%c\n",c[3],c[2],c[1],c[0]);`